# Can Power be < 0.5 For A Symmetric Distribution, Given Rejection?

Tags: statistical-power

It seems to me that if our null and alternative distributions are symmetric, then given that we reject the null hypothesis, our power cannot be below 0.5. Is this true? For example, looking at the following picture, I don't see how we could have a power of < 0.5 while also having the center of the distribution to the right of the critical value (i.e. rejecting the null hypothesis).[image]

Comment: The power $\ge$ alpha level.

Comment: You can certainly have power less than 0.5. In your picture what would happen if the red distribution was shifted to the left? It doesn't have to be centered at the critical value

Comment: I specified "given rejection" though. This means that our test statistic is to the right of the critical value. And with a symmetric distribution, wouldnt the alternative distribution be centered at our test statistic? All these facts make me think that we cannot have a power <0.5 **given rejection and a symmetric alternative** - which one of these assumptions is wrong? My guess is the assumption of having our alternative centered at our test statistic - but why?